# ASP.NET Core static files outside wwwroot folder loading issue

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, static-files

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web application and I have user profile upload and display functionality. I am saving the file in a different folder which is outside of the `wwwroot` folder. I have added to include the outside folder as static files options in `programs.cs` but I'm still unable to display the image.

Here's my code:

`program.cs`:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("S:\\FileRepo")
});
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

`ImagePath` in model:

```
S:\FileRepo\Upload\dc41a1b0-28ee-4910-8010-f728c09c2c78_profilePhoto.jpg
```

And I have used an `<img>` tag in my view page to display the image

```
<img src="S:\FileRepo\Upload\dc41a1b0-28ee-4910-8010-f728c09c2c78_profilePhoto.jpg" alt="Profile Photo">
```

The app is unable to load the image and I am getting this error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///S:/FileRepo/Upload/dc41a1b0-28ee-4910-8010-f728c09c2c78_profilePhoto.jpg

Can you please help me figure out what I am missing?

I tried with static files options. But it still is throwing that error. Is it possible to suggest any other approach or correct the above logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not configure `RequestPath`, the client will directly use the relative path of the file when requesting a static file. You can use `<img src="/Your image.png" alt="Profile Photo">` directly,Or You can also use `RequestPath` to configure the request path for static files.

Here is an example you can use as a reference:

This is the path where I store an outside image:

[image]

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\FileRepo\Upload"),
});
```

Page:

```
<img src="/IMAGE2.png" alt="Profile Photo">
```

Result:
[image]
You can also configure the request path of static files :

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\FileRepo\Upload"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyPath")
});
```

Page:

```
<img src="/MyPath/IMAGE2.png" alt="Profile Photo">
```